# Recover blobs which are falsely line-ending converted with git

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I have a history in git, where in a commit `A` we have a `.gitattributes` files with

```
* text eol=lf
```

which is **clearly** wrong because it will convert all paths to LF even binaries before checkin.
So that happend and I am wondering if a binary file/blob `F` in the history is corrupt (because of crlf got converted to lf) can be restored such that the conversion is undone.

If that procedure is applicable I would apply it in a `git filter-branch` somehow...

PS: I made a new history with a corrected `.gitattribute` file everywhere on `master`

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```

made a new orphan branch `new-master` and rebased the whole `master` onto it. But that does not solve the problem, the file/blobs are left of course corrupt...

Answer (score 0):

If the data stored in the Git repository are not the data you meant to store, no Git command is going to be able to *find* the data that you *did* mean to store.

In other words: no, there is no way to get the correct data from the wrong data.  If you have the correct data somewhere, that's where you get the correct data.

All that `git filter-branch` (or the new and improved `git filter-repo`) can do is *copy* each original commit with some set of filters applied as it goes.  The existing original commit, with its original snapshot, remains in the repository for a while; the new commit, with its new snapshot, is the one that you'll find when using the updated branch name(s) to find commits.